# Grouping raw data into hierarchical structure

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, data-mining, bigdata

I'm working on a pet project which involves grouping raw data (say in csv) into a more organized, useful to me data structure with x nested levels.

Raw Data Eg (scraped data from an online shopping site, say Kindle bookstore):

```
Excel 2013
Excel 2015
Farming practices 101
Cooking 101
Photoshop Basics
```

into:

```
Level 1 -> Level 2 -> Level 3 -> Raw Data Level 4
Office Tools -> Microsoft Products -> Excel -> Excel 2013
Office Tools -> Microsoft Products -> Excel -> Excel 2015
Farming -> Farming Practices -> Basics -> Farming Practices 101
Design -> Photoshop -> Basics -> Photoshop Basics
```

The user can generate the raw data as tags and I want my project to group them into the basic categories (Assuming I have a basic list of the top most level).

Right now, I have a basic knowledge of scraping and grouping but I am looking to group them using some algorithmic way (Big Data, perhaps). Also, I am looking at the AWS DynamoDB +  Redshift just so I can test this out. I don't intend this to be perfect as it is a POC. Has anyone attempted to do this kind of stuff? If yes, how should I go about this? I can provide more specifics in a chat/here as well.

I'm not looking at what to do with the grouped data but looking at how to group the data with an algorithm.

Comment: Do you mean that your program should infer automatically that Excel 2013 belongs to Excel, and that Excel belongs to Microsoft Products? Or does someone prescribe these a-priori relationships? In other words, what is the knowledge base that the program is supposed to use?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way a statistical algorithm can infer from that input data that e.g. Excel is from Microsoft and an Office Tool.

This needs a much larger knowledge base, because that information is not in your input data.

Thus, we can't recommend an algorithm, because none can do this.